# Apache Cassandra Data Modelling for Sensor Data

Tags: json, cassandra, data-modeling

I have a set of metrics that I get from a sensor. The read frequency is about half a second. I'm thinking of using Apache Cassandra to persist these sensor data. Here is exactly what one such data for a single sensor might look like:

```
    "sensor": {
      "123": {
        "externalID": "XXXXX",
        "isEnabled": false,
        "persistence": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "excludedCommands": []
        },
        "readCommands": {
          "BGAGasLevel": "BGAGasLevel.V",
          "CommAliveAsset": "HBD001.STATE.M",
          "CommAliveVPP": "HBD002.STATE.M",
          "MEM.CACHE": "SRV001.MEM.CACHE.V",
          "BLOCK.OUT": "SRV001.BLOCK.OUT.V",
          "setpointFeedback": "CHP1.ActivePower.SetpointFeedback.V",
          "MEM.FREE": "SRV001.MEM.FREE.V",
          "Error": "CHP1.OutOfService.M",
          "Warning": "CHP1.Warning.M",
          "SWAP.IN": "SRV001.SWAP.IN.V",
          "OperatingHours": "CHP1.OperatingHours.V",
          "LAVG5": "SRV001.LAVG5.V",
          "VPPAlive": "VPPAlive.C",
          "SYS.CS": "SRV001.SYS.CS.V",
          "TSODSOAvailability": "CHP1.TSODSOAvailability.M",
          "LAVG1": "SRV001.LAVG1.V",
          "activePower": "CHP1.ActivePower.CurrentValue.V",
          "CPU.WAIT": "SRV001.CPU.WAIT.V",
          "RemoteControlEnabled": "CHP1.RemoteControlEnabled.M",
          "InOperation": "CHP1.InOperation.M",
          "CPU.USER": "SRV001.CPU.USER.V",
          "MEM.SWAPPED": "SRV001.MEM.SWAPPED.V",
          "BGAAlive": "BGAAlive.M",
          "SYS.INT": "SRV001.SYS.INT.V",
          "EnergyCounter": "CHP1.EnergyCounter.V",
          "CPU.SYS": "SRV001.CPU.SYS.V",
          "BGAGasFlameOn": "BGAGasFlameOn.M",
          "CPU.IDLE": "SRV001.CPU.IDLE.V",
          "MEM.BUFFER": "SRV001.MEM.BUFFER.V",
          "BLOCKED": "SRV001.PROCS.BLOCKED.V",
          "BLOCK.IN": "SRV001.BLOCK.IN.V",
          "OutOfService": "CHP1.OutOfService.M",
          "SetpointIsValid": "CHP1.SetpointIsValid.C",
          "LAVG15": "SRV001.LAVG15.V",
          "SWAP.OUT": "SRV001.SWAP.OUT.V"
        },
        "writeCommands": {
          "setpoint": "CHP1.ActivePower.Setpoint.S",
          "SetpointIsValid": "CHP1.SetpointIsValid.C"
        }
      }
    }
```

I will eventually be having millions of such sensors, where a sensor is identified by its id, which is 123 in the case above. Each of those sensors will have different set of commands that I read and write.

So here are my questions:

1. Is Cassandra a good fit for this use case? I have been exploring InfluxDB, OpenTSDB and they have this concept of tags and that seems to fit well, but I would first prefer to see if Cassandra can be a good fit.
2. I would need HA out of the box as I would be reading these data quite frequently. How economical is it to do HA with Cassandra?
3. How is the horizontal scaling with Cassandra? How does this affect the read / write performance?
4. How would persisting JSON data look like? I mean if I get these sensor data in batches as JSON, I would persist the JSON as such to Cassandra.

Comment: when looking at this link http://www.planetcassandra.org/apache-cassandra-use-cases/, you can see that one of the main use case is about sensor data. But I can't answer your other questions sorry

Comment: It would help if you also included what kind of queries you hope to do on the data. Cassandra has very good horizontal scaling, but isn't as good as OpenTSDB for strict time-series queries, like window functions.

Comment: What sort of read query that I would do is still not clear. You can image that I would be building a big reporting infrastructure around the time series data!